# C# Trigger event when sound plays

Tags: c#, windows, audio

I want to create an application that can do something when a certain sound plays. I looked at a couple of options for recording sound from an audio device and it looks promising but I'm still not totally sure how to do this. The sound will be coming from a video game.

Comment: what do you mean The sound will be coming from a video game.

Comment: I would have thought it very hard to monitor the sound output from a game for a specific sound

Comment: I will be playing a video game and the game will play a certain audio file, I want to trigger an event when the sound plays.

Comment: It might feel like a simple thing to do but detecting specific sounds from gameplay audio is something that would be very hard to get working reliably. I assume that the game loads most or all the audio to the memory beforehand so you can't just watch for specific files to be opened/used. Also detecting a specific sound by "listening" to the audio is extremely hard to get right. [See here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-programmatically-detect-a-specific-sound) for more information.